# Copy directory from local to ec2 using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am trying to copy the local directory to ec2 instance. It works fine if I copy a single file not for directory. Any help would be appreciated.

```
resource "null_resource" "cp_ansible" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.provisioner]

  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "../ansible/"
    destination = "/home/ec2-user/ansible/"

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      host        = aws_instance.bastion.public_ip
      user        = "ec2-user"
      private_key = file("/tmp/keys/ec2-key")
      insecure    = true
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
│ Error: file provisioner error
│ 
│   with null_resource.cp_ansible,
│   on inventory.tf line 68, in resource "null_resource" "cp_ansible":
│   68:   provisioner "file" {
│ 
│ Upload failed: scp: /home/ec2-user/ansible/: Is a directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
provisioner "file" {
  source      = "../ansible"
  destination = "/home/ec2-user"

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = aws_instance.bastion.public_ip
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file("/tmp/keys/ec2-key")
    insecure    = true
  }
}
```

From the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/file#directory-uploads):

> The existence of a trailing slash on the source path will determine whether the directory name will be embedded within the destination, or whether the destination will be created. For example:
>
> - If the source is /foo (no trailing slash), and the destination is
>   /tmp, then the contents of /foo on the local machine will be uploaded
>   to /tmp/foo on the remote machine. The foo directory on the remote
>   machine will be created by Terraform.