# I need to upload python program to EC2 using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a basic hello world python program that I am trying to upload using terraform.  When doing so, I am getting a provision error:

```
│ Error: file provisioner error
│ 
│   with aws_instance.ec2_instance,
│   on ec2.tf line 13, in resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance":
│   13:     provisioner "file" {
│ 
│ timeout - last error: dial tcp 3.88.197.68:22: i/o timeout
```

My **resource** file is

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
  ami           = "ami-0889a44b331db0194"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  root_block_device {
    volume_size = var.ebs_volume_size
  }
    connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ec2-user"  # Replace with your desired SSH username
    host        = self.public_ip
  }
    provisioner "file" {
    source      = "hello_world.py"
    destination = "/home/ec2-user/hello_world.py"
  }
    provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "python /home/ec2-user/hello_world.py"
    ]
  }
}
```

```
variable "instance_type" {
  description = "The EC2 instance type"
  type        = string
  default     = "t2.micro"  # Replace with your desired default instance type
}

variable "ebs_volume_size" {
  description = "EBS Volume"
  type        = number
  default     = 10  # Replace with your desired default volume size
}
```

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-east-1"  # Update with your desired region
}
```

I tried to update the source to different values, but I am not having any luck.
`

```
Try 1: /Users/Ashish/Documents/Terraform-on-aws-ec2/EC2-Terraform/hello_world.py
```

```
Try 2: Documents/Terraform-on-aws-ec2/EC2-Terraform/hello_world.py
```

```
Try 3: hello_world.py`
```

Wondering if any one seen this issue.  I also tried to follow this link. [Copy directory from local to ec2 using terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72322211/copy-directory-from-local-to-ec2-using-terraform)

Comment: What are the security group for the instance?

Comment: The error is you can't connect via ssh. That port isn't open most likely due to either due to routing or security groups

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `terraform provider`.  If you want to deploy `python` from `yum` (for instance), this is your plugin:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/datadrivers/nexus/latest/docs/resources/repository_yum_proxy

I would use `git`, and `gitops` is trendy.  This is not necessarily the provider I would use, it is one of many:

```
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/tyler-technologies/gitops/latest
```

The terraform provider registry is here:

```
https://registry.terraform.io/
```

Each provider has it's own unique resource names, attributes, etc; so what the code would look like for your deployment will depend on the provider you use.  The documentation for these plugins are sufficient to be able to guide you to create the resources and get results you need.  I am sure other SO posters can give you examples of various providers, if you need direction there.